# how do i get this mod_rewrite to work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to force a redirect of all request to

```
http://website.com/
```

to

```
http://website.com/2013/04/
```

doing this

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Multiviews

RewriteRule ^2013/03/ index.html
```

will direct any request from

```
website.com/2013/03/ to the index.html
```

but how do I force the redirect to website.com/2013/03/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To make your URL lovely and suitable for search engine ranking.**

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9} /index.html HTTP/
 RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.yoursite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

**To redirect**

```
redirect 301 /old-page.php http://www.yoursite.com/new-page.php
```